# ASP.NET Paypal IPN returning VERIFIED but IPN Fails to Send

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I will try to get straight to the point. I am currently working with PayPal IPN and have never seen this issue before. I have used PayPal IPN and my implementations have always been the same. This time however it is producing some very weird results.

I am currently hosted with WinHost.com

Code Used:

```
public void MakeHttpPost()
    {

        ErrorLog log = new ErrorLog();
        //Post back to either sandbox or live
        string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = HttpContext.Current.Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //for proxy
        //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
        //req.Proxy = proxy;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();
        log.error = strResponse;
        log.Insert();

        if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {
            PaypalPaymentHistory PPH = new PaypalPaymentHistory();

            PPH.LastName = HttpContext.Current.Request["last_name"];
            PPH.FirstName = HttpContext.Current.Request["first_name"];
            PPH.State = HttpContext.Current.Request["address_state"];
            PPH.Zipcode = HttpContext.Current.Request["address_zip"];
            PPH.Address = HttpContext.Current.Request["address_street"];
            PPH.UserName = HttpContext.Current.Request["option_name2"];
            PPH.PaymentStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request["payment_status"];
            PPH.SelectedPackage = HttpContext.Current.Request["option_selection1"];
            PPH.PayerStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request["payer_status"];
            PPH.PaymentType = HttpContext.Current.Request["payment_type"];
            PPH.PayerEmail = HttpContext.Current.Request["payer_email"];
            PPH.ReceiverId = HttpContext.Current.Request["receiver_id"];
            PPH.TxnType = HttpContext.Current.Request["txn_type"];
            PPH.PaymentGross = HttpContext.Current.Request["payment_gross"];

            PPH.Insert();

        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
            //log for manual investigation
        }
        else
        {
            //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
        }

    }
```

The idea here is that I will check the status of the order and then insert or not insert the record to the database but this code is still in tests so nothing is official.

The problem I am having is that when I run through sandbox and make a payment via my site paypal sends out the IPN request. The entry gets thrown into the database and all the data is sent back correctly however PayPal is showing that the IPN Post "Failed" and is always stuck on "Retrying". However I am getting "VERIFIED" back in strResponse. This in turn is causing up to 8 records per transaction. The error that paypal is reporting is 500 - Internal Server Error. Any help would be insanely appreciated as this has been a 2 day head bashing marathon up to this point!

Thanks for any help or resolutions!

P.S I have read nearly every IPN question on stackoverflow and have seen nothing like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your controller action is failing if PayPal reports a `500`.  You need to debug that code and see what is failing.  If your controller does not send a `200` back, PayPal will keep trying.

I always do this:

```
    public ActionResult IPN()
    {     
        //try catch log all my payment info

        //always return blank page so paypal gets a HTTP 200
        return View();
    }
```

//you may know this, but for others, here is an example process flow

1. Payment/transaction made to PayPal
2. IPN address is configured for PayPal transaction then posts to the IPN address ie: http://yourdomain.com/IPN.aspx
3. IPN.aspx handles the IPN post and writes PaypalPaymentHistory to db.

Comment: I have the controller that calls that function WWW.site.com/payment/processpayment that is the link in the paypal ipn box

Comment: I'm getting the outback from paypal showing verified however paypal is showing failed and constantly retires the post to my controllers action ProcessPayment which calls MakeHttpPost

Comment: The controller is very bare bones, the only that that is in it is my object PPIPN PP = new PPIPN("TEST") and then PP.MakeHttpPost(). I don't see how it could be failing.
http://www.mysite.com/payment/processpayment
Is this not a correct IPN address to input into paypal?
Really appreciate your help Rick.

Comment: Take that code out or try catch it and see what happens, a 500 is your servers code failing.

Comment: IPN successfully sent. Thank you very much Rick, you showed me my problem without even knowing the exact issue. I feel like a complete idiot but I guess that's what happens when you tunnel vision on a problem for too long. The issue was that my controller was calling ProcessPayment() then returning a blank View however that View was not created under the Payment View Folder which was causing it to return a 500 instead of 200. Problem is 110% resolved. Thank you very much!

Comment: Rick, thanks for this. The concept of sending no response resulting in a `500 Internal Server Error` never occurred to me until reading your answer here. If you're up for it, it might be worth while for others to see how to give Paypal a blank page (for me, `return View();` did nothing, but I was able to use `Response.Clear(); Response.StatusCode = 200; Response.Write(""); Response.End();`

Comment: You have to have a empty View called "IPN" for my solution to work.

Comment: Bless you, this also happens to fix my issue I spent 2 days on on PHP - Apache/Linux.  No view means no 200 response.  Add a view ~_~